# Неправильно считает сумму. Подскажите, в чем ошибка

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры двумерный массив целых чисел, заносит в одномерный массив суммы неотрицательных элементов по строкам, выводит этот массив на экран до первого нулевого элемента и отображает число оставшихся элементов.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int i, j, n, m;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "m=";
    cin >> m;
    int**mas = new int*[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> mas[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ "<<"\n";
    int *mas1 = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++);
            {
                if (mas[i][j] >= 0)
                    sum += mas[i][j];
                    mas1[i] = sum;
            }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout <<mas1[i]<< " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: пример работы программы. сумму выводит как ноль]

Comment: по мне вроде все правильно. нет отрицательных элементов, вот и  0 0

Comment: Наконец-то я увидел этот код живьем :) Всегда считал, что `for(....); { ... }` - это придумки авторов учебников...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас стоит точка с запятой

```
for (j = 0; j < m; j++);
                      ^^^
```

Уберите ее.

Логически лучше было записать циклы как

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (mas[i][j] >= 0)
                sum += mas[i][j];
        }
        mas1[i] = sum;
}
```